# how to use bixolon sdk for phonegap app in javascript code?

Tags: javascript, cordova, bixolon-printer

I'm developing an android app using phonegap. My app has javascript, angularjs, ionic and I need to print an image and a codebar with **bixolon SPP-R200 printer**. I've tried with bixolon sdk phonegap sample **bixolon.js** plugin but I don't know how it works. I tried everything and nothing works, if somebody knows how to use it or know another plugin that works and can help me, I'll appreciate this a lot

Comment: have you read this ? https://github.com/oscb/bixolon-printers-plugin

Comment: Yes, I have, actually i did see all github's plugins and none allow print images or barcode. I used alfonsovinti's plugin to print text, but i need more than text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that needs something like my question, this plugin does anything. Print images, text and barcodes. take a look!. By the way, It works with any bluetooth printer. Have fun!

[Bluetooth Printer Plugin](https://github.com/giorgiofellipe/cordova-plugin-datecs-printer)